# Purchasing OS X Mavericks for a fresh install

Tags: macos, apple-id, install

I have a Mac Mini here that I just reset (wiped everything). When I try to reinstall OS X Mavericks through the "Install OS X" interface, I am seeing this error message:

> **This Apple ID has not purchased "OS X Mavericks".**
>
> You must sign in with an Apple ID that was used to purchase "OS X
>   Mavericks".

How do I purchase "OS X Mavericks"? Weirdly I was not able to find anything online. I do not have access to a different Apple device or physical media.

Answer (score 1):

To install OS X Mavericks, the Apple ID that you enter **must have Mavericks in the purchase history**. If Mavericks is missing, the installer will not let you proceed.

If you had another machine, you could download Mavericks using your Apple ID so that it's registered with your Apple ID. If you even have access to a friend's Mac, you could use that to register the installer.

If that's not an option, you could go to the Apple Store, [as was discussed over on ASC](https://discussions.apple.com/message/24140456#24140456):

> I solved the problem by going to the apple store and they reset things for me by installing Snow Leopard on it again. It wasn't until my second visit though so yes they might take a while.

Answer (score 0):

In the future, your best bet would be to purchase Mavericks from the app store, run the installer, THEN wipe the drive and re-run the installer.

Right now, you have 3 options:

1. Call apple, give them your Apple ID, and purchase Mavericks over the phone if they will let you. Have them walk you through the installation.
2. Make a appointment at the genius bar at the closest apple store to purchase and install Mavericks. (If there is an apple store nearby, this is the most likely to work).
3. Install an old operating system using the optical disks that came with your mac, then purchase Mavericks from the app store and run the installer.

How are you pulling up the "Install OS X" interface?